# Monthly GIMMS NDVI time series

Tags: ndvi, google-earth-engine

I need to create a monthly NDVI time series from GIMMS in GEE (i.e. from January 1981 to December 2013) from the sum of fortnight values (or mean).
I've been trying to create a function to do so, but can't figure it out.

I try this code, but generates annual sums, not monthly sums...

```js
var monthly = 
mageCollection.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(1981,2013,'year'))
.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(1,12,'month')).sum();
```

Comment: The code appears to be incomplete. How is the variable "mageCollection" defined?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue before... I tried to do the same thing with MODIS, so, I asked at Stack Overflow.

Based on an [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47102922/double-loop-with-map-function-in-google-earth-engine) from [Rodrigo E. Principe](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/23470/rodrigo-e-principe), you should apply two `map()` functions to filter by month and year. Inside one created function, you can add `sum()` to sums for each month by year:

```js
var imageCollection = ee.ImageCollection("NASA/GIMMS/3GV0");
print(imageCollection);

var years = ee.List.sequence(1981, 2013);
var months = ee.List.sequence(1, 12);

var map_m = function(i) {
  i = ee.Number(i);
  var filtered_col = years.map(function(j) {
    var filtered = imageCollection
        .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(i, i, 'month'))
        .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(j, j, 'year'))
        .select(0)
        .sum();
    return filtered;
  });
  return filtered_col;
};

var img_col = ee.ImageCollection(months.map(map_m).flatten());

print(img_col);

var checkImage = ee.Image(img_col.filter(ee.Filter.eq('system:index', '10')).first());
Map.addLayer(checkImage, {min:-1,max:1}, 'test');
```

Link to reproducible example: https://code.earthengine.google.com/cb8422e2d888fd3cd85f57db5920d917